# Remove Dynamic TextField as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, sdk, textfield, articulate-storyline

I'm trying to modifying an articulate storyline sdk.(https://www.articulate.com/support/storyline/articulate-storyline-sdk)

They are using as3 and created all textfield dynamically like the code below

```
if (this.textField != null)
            { 
                if (m_bWrapListItems)
                {
                    this.textField.Autosize = true;
                    this.textField.Wrap = true;
                    if (m_bAutoNumber)
                    {
                        this.textField.SetHangingIndent(m_strNumber);
                        this.textField.Text = m_strNumber + "\t" + m_strTitle;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    this.textField.Truncate = true;
                    this.textField.ClearHangingIndent();
                    this.textField.Text = (!m_bAutoNumber) ? m_strNumber + " " + m_strTitle : m_strTitle;
                }
```

Now I want to delete some textfield after creating please help to solve this problem.

Comment: You've just to remove them as any DisplayObject using [removeChild()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#removeChild()), for example ... I don't see what's your problem exactly ?!

Comment: The code you've show doesn't create or display a text field. Also, the `textField` property is not a standard AS3 `TextField` because it has a lot of properties that are not found on `TextField`. I don't think there's much anyone can do to help with the information you've given. Maybe Articulate can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Set to Null ?
this.textField = null;

Comment: I don't want to remove this textField. I want to remove all the dynamics Textfield later in my program

Comment: This textfield Only removes the current textfield which is selected.I want to remove rest of the textfields too